# CSS property applied after inspect element

Tags: html, css

I'm now working on this site [egtripper.com](http://egtripper.com/) and when the page load the slider section doesn't be in the center as expected, and this the css for slider

```
.slider {
width: 1000px;
height: 330px;
margin: 30px auto;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative; }
```

but when I try to inspect the slider with chrome tools, its position fixed immediately

Can anyone help me, Thanks

Comment: It looks centered for me http://prntscr.com/2o7zi8 With Firefox 26

Comment: @AdamAzad Chrome/// *but when I try to inspect the slider with chrome tools*

Comment: I would delete my answer as it was poorly written, also your question doesn't suffice site rules, so you should try, include some code here and see if you get some help

Answer (score 0):

Just suggesting, but you could wrap .slider with a DIV 100% width, overflow hidden and position relative.

And try removing 'min-width', if it is possible.